# When running elevated command in Powershell. Does the intial window always stay open?

Tags: powershell

May sound like a redundant question. But I made a PowerShell script with an interactive menu to combine multiple scripts in one file.

However, since I have added the interactive menu. The initial window is staying open and replicating the menu on the non elevated window.

Is there anything I can add so that this first window closes?

Example...

```
if (!(
    [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(
    [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"
))
{
    Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs
}

function Show-Menu
{
     param (
           [string]$Title = 'Add Windows Firewall Rules'
     )
     cls
     Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
    
     Write-Host "1: Press '1' to add new firewall Rules WIN10."
     Write-Host "2: Press '2' to add import new Firewall Rules WIN7."
     Write-Host "3: Press '3' to confirm the new rules have been added."
     Write-Host "4: Press '4' to close this tool."
}
```

Comment: `-NoNewWindow` should help with this.

Comment: Add `Exit` after the line `Start-Process  powershell.exe ...` because you want to exit the current script and run the script new with elevated permissions.

Comment: `PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

As commented, when you tested the script is run **without** admin permissions, you need to start the script again **with** admin rights, and then.. Quit the currently running (unelevated) script, so its window closes and only the elevated instance is running.

```
# test if the script is run as Administrator
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
    # start the script again, this time with -Verb RunAs
    Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs
    # now EXIT this unelevated instance of PowerShell
    Exit
}
```